# How to convert multi level xml to a single line containing all levels using XMLSTARLET

Tags: xmlstarlet

The sample XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <level01>
    <field01>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</field01>
    <field02>BBBBBBBB</field02>
    <field03>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</field03>
    <field04>DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</field04>
    <field05>DDD</field05>
    <level02>
      <field01>EEEEEEEEE</field01>
      <field02>FFF</field02>
      <field04>GGGGGGGGGGs</field04>
      <field05>HHH</field05>
      <level03>
        <field01>IIIIIIIII</field01>
        <field02>JJJ</field02>
        <field04>KKKKKKKKK</field04>
        <field05>L</field05>
      </level03>
    </level02>
  </level01>
</root>
```

The desired output looks like:

```
AAAAAA,BBBBB, CCCCCCCCCCCCC ,DDDDDDDDDD ,DDD,EEE,FFF,GGGG,HHH,III,JJJ,KKK,L
```

Comment: How important are the spaces in the comma-separated fields of your output? I don't see those spaces in your input file, and they're not consistent..

Comment: Does the solution have to use `xmlstarlet` or can any suitable tool be used?

Comment: and why are some fields truncated in the output to 3 or 4 characters while others are full-length?

Answer (score 2):

**xmlstartlet** arguments are a little bit tricky. You have to see
them as templtes (-t) in the xsl way...

```
xmlstarlet sel -B -t -m '//text()' -c 'concat(.,",")' x1.xml
```

where:

- -B : generically remove spaces
- -t : template in the xsl sense
- -m : match xpath exp
- -c : copy-of xpath exp

This expression, produces an extra ",". Naturally we can uses normal
Unix tools to help:

```
xmlstarlet sel -B -t -v '//text()' x1.xml | 
    sed -z 's/\n/, /g; s/$/\n/'
```

- -t : a template (in xsl sense)
- -v : value-of (xpath expression)
- sed... to trim ,

Answer (score 1):

Using [xml2](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/) (available packaged for debian and most other distros) instead of `xml2starlet`, along with `awk` and `paste`:

```
$ xml2 <sdfsdf.xml | awk -F= '{ print $2 }' | paste -sd,
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBB,CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC,DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD,DDD,EEEEEEEEE,FFF,GGGGGGGGGGs,HHH,IIIIIIIII,JJJ,KKKKKKKKK,L
```

if you want spaces after each comma, add them with `sed`:

```
xml2 <sdfsdf.xml | awk -F= '{ print $2 }' | paste -sd, | sed -e 's/,/, /g'
```

`cut` can also work in place of `awk` but I'm guessing there's other criteria you haven't mentioned yet, so I'll stick with `awk` for now.  Anyway, here's the `cut` version:

```
xml2 <sdfsdf.xml | cut -d= -f2 | paste -sd,
```